# Interface suspended when linking access to core

Tags: cisco, etherchannel, stacking

Some help required please.

I have a stack which contains two access switches, and an interface from switch 1 has a successful link to the core.

However, when I try adding a secondary link on switch 2 back to the core, the interface is in a suspended state.

**Access Stack**

```
switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
 channel-protocol lacp
 channel-group 1 mode active
```

**Core Switch**

```
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100,120,200,300-302,400-403,700,900-902
 switchport mode trunk
 no keepalive
 channel-protocol lacp
 channel-group 1 mode active
```

**Access Stack Interface**

```
GigabitEthernet3/0/47 is up, line protocol is down (suspended)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 40a6.e851.bb2f (bia 40a6.e851.bb2f)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     82 packets input, 5248 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 82 broadcasts (82 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 82 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

**Core Switch Interface**

```
GigabitEthernet0/42 is up, line protocol is down (suspended)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet, address is 3c08.f63a.16aa (bia 3c08.f63a.16aa)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not set
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:44:02, output 00:00:28, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 68
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     34339 packets input, 7966960 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 5778 broadcasts (2018 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 2018 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     59283 packets output, 44210435 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Is there something wrong with my config that's causing this?

EDIT:
On both interfaces from the core and the access stack, there is a stationary amber light which usually indicates STP has suspended the port to avoid a loop.

**Port Channel 1 (Access Stack)**

```
Port-channel1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is EtherChannel, address is 40a6.e8ba.a530 (bia 40a6.e8ba.a530)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 2/255, rxload 20/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, link type is auto, media type is unknown
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  Members in this channel: Gi1/0/48
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 3151
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 8118000 bits/sec, 1396 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 1141000 bits/sec, 939 packets/sec
     7569694044 packets input, 3273308277235 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 3873169150 broadcasts (2541283760 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 2541283760 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     2240014676 packets output, 349722616455 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

**Port Channel 1 (Core Switch)**

```
Port-channel1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is EtherChannel, address is 3c08.f63a.1682 (bia 3c08.f63a.1682)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 21/255, rxload 3/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not set
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, link type is auto, media type is unknown
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported
  Members in this channel: Gi0/2
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 430857
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 1200000 bits/sec, 984 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 8536000 bits/sec, 1472 packets/sec
     5529865138 packets input, 817634236496 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 115285777 broadcasts (109549995 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 109549995 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     17791035271 packets output, 7051584854682 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 PAUSE output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

**Etherchannel Summary (Core)**

```
Group  Port-channel  Protocol    Ports
------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
1      Po1(SU)         LACP      Gi0/2(P)    Gi0/3(w)    Gi0/42(s)
2      Po2(SU)         LACP      Gi0/47(P)   Gi0/48(P)
3      Po3(SU)         LACP      Te1/1(P)    Te1/2(P)
```

**Etherchannel Summary (Stack)**

```
Group  Port-channel  Protocol    Ports
------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------
1      Po1(SU)         LACP      Gi1/0/48(P) Gi2/0/48(D) Gi3/0/47(s)
```

Comment: Typically you can see in the log of the switches, what the reason is for the suspension. Maybe it's because the access switch is trunk nonegotiate, you could try to remove it. When working with port-channels everything typically needs to be configured exactly the same in both ends and on both port-channel and interface.

Comment: How would I check the logs? I've basically mirrored the first link to the core with the exact same config, and it's not working, so it could be a switching loop.

Comment: @BabyPython Can you please post the configuration of Po1 interface on Access and Core as well?

Comment: @BabyPython show logging on the device.

Comment: @HungTran I've updated this information in the question for review. You will see that he interfaces are different because the interfaces I'm trying to use for this port channel are not currently members, even though I've entered `channel-group 1 mode active` on both interfaces

Comment: @BabyPython your port-channel says `Full-duplex, 100Mb/s` you cannot bundle 100 Mbit interfaces with Gigabit interfaces.

Comment: @cown The primary link I have to the core is configured with `Full-duplex, 100Mb` on both sides and this works, so it does seem possible, but perhaps not the best way?

Comment: @BabyPython yes it works, but you cannot mix 100 Mbit with 1 Gbit links.

Comment: @Cown Perhaps this is an issue with the cabling, if it's not auto negotiating 1000mb/s?

Comment: @BabyPython could be, are the current interfaces gigabit also? Could you post the output of: `show etherchannel summary`?

Comment: @Cown This has now been updated in the question. The current interfaces are running at 100mb/s so perhaps it's not as efficient as it should be.

Comment: @BabyPython Well if the cabling is defective that could be a reason for the 100Mbit negotiation. What is the configuration of the running interfaces? You could force them to run Gbit by using `speed 1000` and `duplex full` but it will mean downtime in order to try it out. I actually think the `nonegotiate` is the reason it might be running 100 Mbit.

Comment: Sometimes, bringing up a port channel can be tricky. Shut down the channel and physical interfaces on both sides, Then on one side, bring up the channel interface, then bring up the physical interfaces. Once you have done that, repeat for the other side.

Comment: @Cown I was under the impression that nonegotiate took care of ensuring that it's a trunk on both sides, not related to speed. Also, the way this is configured with nonegotiate is configured like this on other switches with port channels, and they work fine with double redundancy back to the core. I think in the first instance I'll check if Cat5e is being used here for that auto negotiation of the speed, failing that I will try removing nonegotiate for this switch to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @BabyPython You are right, nonegotiate has nothing to do with speed. DTP is used by Cisco switches to negotiate whether an interconnection between two switches should be put into access or trunk mode. It is meant both to ease the initial deployment of a switched network and to minimize configuration errors that result from mismatched port configuration on an interconnection between two switches.

Comment: @Cown Do you think that stacking could cause potential issues here? As switch 1 in the stack already has redundancy back to the core through the port channel, could this cause problems when trying to introduce another link?

Comment: @BabyPython No i don't think so.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I haven't got a reputation score of 50 yet so can't add to the comments... But following on from what @Cown was saying here are the guidelines from Cisco:

All ports must be identical:
- Same speed & duplex
- Cannot mix Fast Ethernet & Gigabit Ethernet
- Cannot mix PAgP & LACP
- Must all be VLAN trunk or nontrunk operational status
- All VLANs and allowed VLANs must match
- All links must be L2 or L3 in a single channel group
- All trunk links are in the same mode ISL or Dot1Q